# Changing interface into type with module augmentation in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

Is it possible to change `interface` into `type` when augmenting modules with TS?
I want to enhance Theme in Material-UI with some of my own properties. I created `createPalette.d.ts` file:

```
import '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette';

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  export interface PaletteOptions {
    neutral?: {
      moderate: string;
      dark: string;
    };
  }
  export interface Palette {
    neutral: {
      moderate: string;
      dark: string;
    };
  }
}
```

Contents of `PaletteOptions` and `Palette` interfaces will be almost identical, so I wanted to simplify it a little bit by extracting `neutral` as external type and come up with something like this:

```
import '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette';

type CustomPalette = {
  neutral: {
    moderate: string;
    dark: string;
  };
};

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  export interface PaletteOptions extends Partial<CustomPalette> {}
  export interface Palette extends CustomPalette {}
}
```

It works, but `PaletteOptions` and `Palette` are now considered "empty" and I get errors because of `no-empty-interfaces` rule. After hitting auto-fix ESLint changed it to types:

```
import '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette';

type CustomPalette = {
  neutral: {
    moderate: string;
    dark: string;
  };
};

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  export type PaletteOptions = Partial<CustomPalette>;
  export type Palette = CustomPalette;
}
```

There is no ESLint error, but now module augmentation doesn't work, because Material-UI typings declare `PaletteOptions` and `Palette` as interfaces and TS ignores my declarations.
What are my options now? Is there any way to trick TS into accepting `PaletteOptions` and `Palette` being types or should I just go with `eslint-ignore` on that rule?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the rule is assuming that you're not augmenting, and it would be safe to disable it, as you'll need another interface to augment the existing interface.